# Add column to existing table and default value to another column without dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

For Sql Server 2005 and 2008 I want to check if a column already exists on a given table and create it if it doesn't. This new column should have a default value of an ExistingColumn. Currently I need to use dynamic sql to fill the new column because sql server will complain of a syntax error.

Here is the current sql server code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'NewColumn' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'ExistingTable'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExistingTable] ADD [NewColumn] VARCHAR(50) NULL;

    exec sp_executesql  N'UPDATE [dbo].[ExistingTable] SET NewColumn = ExistingColumn'

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExistingTable] ALTER COLUMN  [NewColumn] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
END
GO
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem without resorting to dynamic sql?

Comment: why don't you like dynamic sql as a solution?

Comment: I don't have a problem with it aside from not getting the syntax highlighting and auto complete of Management Studio. More curious as to whats really going on under the covers.

Comment: Ah, I usually replace the exec with Print, then paste that in another window it's not brill but it's better that trying to figure out what error near , means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating the column regardless, you could do two separate batches.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'NewColumn' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'ExistingTable'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExistingTable] ADD [NewColumn] VARCHAR(50) NULL;
    END
    GO
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'NewColumn' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'ExistingTable'))
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[ExistingTable] WHERE NewColumn IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo].[ExistingTable] SET NewColumn = ExistingColumn
            ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExistingTable] ALTER COLUMN  [NewColumn] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
        END
    END
    GO
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll still get the error if you run the second batch on its own without having ran the first batch or if the first batch errors; all the above does is get you out of doing dynamic SQL. So if you're looking for repeatability, then you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server is parsing your statement *before* your `ALTER` runs, and saying "Hey, no such column." The parser doesn't understand `IF` and other branching and can't follow the sequence of events when you mix DDL and DML - or predict the sequence the events will take and what branching will happen at runtime.

Deferred name resolution allows you to access *objects* that don't exist yet, but not *columns* that don't exist yet on objects that do.

So, dynamic SQL seems like the way you'll have to do it.